# Spring JPA-Repository Query Methods and Parameter is Null Issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I ran into a problem with query method of a repository.

I defined a method like:

```
List<Person> findByForenameAndSurname(String forename, String surname).
```

Issuing this method with a surname of `null` suddenly produced all persons having the same forename. I had multiple entries in my table but expected none. I read that the behavior is known and that I should use `findByForenameAndSurnameIsNull` if I want to search for exactly `null`.

We upgraded our dependencies from 4.1.7 to 4.3.9 and now the behavior has changed. I am not sure if this was related to some annotations of the entity property in question or if it is the version change.

Does someone has any information on this different behavior of null handling when it comes to the query process by specifying a method in within a repository interface.

PS: Using Hibernate as the persistence provider, no special configuration.

Comment: Did you check this https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-209

Comment: Thanks for the link thats interesting. The reporter of the issue mentions not seeing any result. My problem was contrary. I saw more results because the property being null was ignored alltogether. We checked with a different query yesterday, the SQL being produced was correct. I currently try to reproduce the original problem but failed. There are reports about this being the case some time ago but I saw it last weeks but we changed the depnendencies, thats what can contribute to my missery.